# Converting joda LocalTime to sql Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to convert a LocalTime object to a java.sql.Time object.

```
java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(new LocalTime(1,0,0,0).getMillisOfDay());
System.out.println(time); //20:00:00
```

The above code, instead of creating a Time object with a value equal to 01:00:00, creates an object with a time of 20:00:00. The local time is eastern time.

What steps should I take?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Time(..)` accepts a timestamp starting from 1970. So you should pass that:

`new Time(new LocalTime(...).toDateTimeToday().getMillis())`

Answer (score 7):

I consider the currently accepted answer to be incorrect. Although java.sql.Time implies that its date fields are set to 1970-1-1, this is not true. If you use the conversion

```
new java.sql.Time(new LocalTime(...).toDateTimeToday().getMillis())
```

then the internal millesecond representation of the java.sql.Time object will reflect today's date. This leads to unexpected behavior when comparing java.sql.Time objects.
Comparisons are performed on the millisecond value, and if the underlying dates are different, the time fields are irrelevant to the comparison result

A better method, is to explicitly work with the time-fields, using the deprecated constructor and methods in java.sql.Time:

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(1,0,0,0);
java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(localTime.getHourOfDay(), localTime.getMinuteOfHour(), localTime.getSecondOfMinute())
```

Similarly, in the other direction

```
java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(1,0,0);
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(sqlTime.getHours(), sqlTime.getMinues(), sqlTime.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Using deprecated methods is bad practice.

Comment: Sure it is, but you've got to know when to break the rules. These deprecated methods are the simplest and most efficient way to achieve the goal, and there are no plans to remove them from Java in the foreseeable future. Frankly, Sun should never have deprecated them; the horrible mess that replaces them is the entire reason to move to the cleaner implementation like JodaTime.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a hole in the Joda Time API. Right now `getLocalMillis()` is `protected`, but that's exactly the method I'd want to use.

However, if you want to avoid deprecated methods, you can figure out time on January 1, 1970:

```
LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(1, 23, 45, 678);
long millis = lt.toDateTimeToday().withDate(1970, 1, 1).getMillis()
java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(millis);
```

This seems to work. Interestingly, I tried figuring out the millis by multiplying the values of the fields out. That produced the right `long` value, but when I passed it to the `Time` constructor, something weird happened with the time zone. (I think, at least. The `Time` value ended up five hours before the value I passed in, and I'm on Eastern Daylight Time, so I think that's what happened.)

Answer (score -1):

i found another way to convert the *java.time.LocalTime* to *java.time.LocalTime*

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
Time time = Time.valueOf(localTime);
```

Comment: The question is regarding LocalTime in Joda-Time, not the LocalTime class added in Java 8.