# How to create a joda time duration from java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, time, jodatime, sql-types

Hello I have this excerpt of code:

```
end = new DateTime(mergeToDateTime(this.endDate, this.empEndTime));

Duration extraTime = new Duration(this.preTime.getTime()); //add the first 30 mins
extraTime = extraTime.plus(new Duration(this.postTime.getTime())); //add the second 30 mins
end = end.plus(extraTime); // extraTime = -3600?
```

When I look in the debugger my durations are always coming up negative. I have no idea why this is, even though according to the [API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/Duration.html), it is possible to create a duration out of the a *long* type, hence the ***getTime()***. (**preTime** and **postTime** are **java.sql.Time** types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your instances of `java.sql.Time` were created in such a way that their millisecond values include timezone offset.

For example, deprecated `java.sql.Time(int hour, int minute, int second)` constructor takes offset of the current timezone into account:

```
System.out.println(new Time(1, 0, 0).getTime()); // Prints -7200000 in UTC+3 timezone
```

It looks like timezone offset is introduced by JDBC driver, and it can be easily compensated by converting `java.sql.Time` to `LocalTime` ([and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422753/converting-joda-localtime-to-sql-time)):

```
LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(time);
```

Then you can convert `LocalTime` to duration:

```
Duration d = new Duration(lt.getMillisOfDay());
```

Comment: What would be the best way to create a duration from a java.sql.Time?

Comment: @Dark: It depends on where do these `Time`s come from and what do they mean. If you have a `Time` that conceptually represents a duration (for example, `new Time(3600000)` is an exact duration of 1 hour), you can convert it as shown in your question. If `Time` represents something different, it's not clear how to convert it to duration.

Comment: The time is a java.sql.time which is stored in a MySQL Database as a TIME type. It literally is supposed to represent a duration in hours and minutes devoid of timeZone semantics. The only problem with what the way I do it is that it returns a negative time duration so instead of +1 hour I get -1 hour.

Comment: Nope. They're stored in the dbase in the HH:mm:ss format. I have a feeling the getTime() method is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid shuttling the data through an intermediate variable but I already arrived at this solution

Comment: Just to note that there is another way to convert an sql Time to a LocalTime, [fromDateFields](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#fromDateFields%28java.util.Date%29), which may be useful as it only uses the getters on SQL time.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you starting out wrong when you use an instant in time as duration? The constructor signature you are using is `Duration(long duration)`, not `Duration(long startInstant)` -- there is no such constructor, in fact.

Comment: I am not using an instance in time, rather I am using a time value. My variable is stored in the database purely in a time format representing 30mins (HH:mm:ss => 00:30:00) as opposed to an instant in time, which would also contain a date, hence the reason I use the .getTime() which returns a long value of the time. (at least that's what the java doc indicated)

Comment: That's why you have your problem, then, as described in the accepted answer. The database type you are using is for instants and you are abusing it for intervals.